# Unable to get Facebook Checkins of my friends

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am successfull to get my own checkins using this code

```
$checkins = $this->facebook->api("/me/checkins?limit=1000");
```

But I am not able to get my friend's checkin using this code

```
$checkins = $this->facebook->api("/$friend_id/checkins?limit=1000");
my_var_dump($checkins);
```

I am getting empty array while i do var_dump()
Is that Facebook API bug or I am doing something wrong?
Permission given are user_status, friends_status

It does not even work even when i check this on Graph API Explorer on Facebook.
Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Test it in the API explorer of Facebook, If there's an error or missing permission it will let you know.

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to this? I have been having this EXACT problem all day. My code looks almost identical to yours.. lol